# arima: How can I get fitted ARIMA time series?

Tags: r, time-series, predict

```
m7 = arima(lill,order=c(0,0,1),
          seasonal=list(order=c(1,0,0),period=22),
          xreg=data.frame(lpGDP))

preds = predict(m7,n.ahead = 1, newxreg = 1)
```

There are 329 observations in `lill` object. How can I predict the last observation 328, instead of 330 observation? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to call `predict` for prediction of observed data. You can do:

```
fitted_values <- lill - m7$residuals
```

This is the fitted ARIMA model. To inspect the 328th value, do

```
fitted_values[328]
```

I don't have your data, so I use R's built-in data set `LakeHuron` as a toy demonstration.

```
fit <- arima(LakeHuron, order = c(2,0,0), xreg = time(LakeHuron) - 1920)
fitted_values <- LakeHuron - fit$residuals
ts.plot(LakeHuron)  ## observed time series (black)
lines(fitted_values, col = 2)  ## fitted time series (red)
```

[image: toy]